# Track user activity using Audit tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to implement a way to track changes to a table named gsbirst_Objects and gsbirst_Objects_Backup. It will record DML and Truncate statements

I have a stored procedure that will update the main table when it is called. How can I capture changes at the beginning and end when the stored procedure is called

I have created the backup table

Comment: Have you checked SQL Server's [built-in auditing features?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The auditing article mentions that auditing is built on top of extended events. You can do the same and capture specific events into a target of your choice, eg a table. That's no different from capturing queries for profiling. *Data* changes is a different matter. SQL Server also offers [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and since SQL Server 2016, [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to track number of changes in column from SQL database via power query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290947/is-there-a-way-to-track-number-of-changes-in-column-from-sql-database-via-power)

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while back using triggers it isn't the best way but works. You can create an audit table them build a trigger for each action. I made a trigger ON DELETE, ON UPDATE, and ON INSERT. I would then grab the record that was changed up dated or deleted and concatenate the row together and load a before and after into the audit table depending on what happened. This route for me gave me a little more detailed even of what happened and what changed.